# Look for words in a textbox text and display in data grid

Tags: c#, textbox

I need to program a windows form in c#, it needs a textBox and a button. in the textbox I have to type a programming instruction for example:
for(i=0;i<10;i++)

then click a button and in the datagrid it should be displayed something like this:

1. for - cycle
2. ( - agrupation
3. i - variable
4. = - asignation

   and so on

how can I identify the parts of the text?

I've tried foreach char but I'm really messed up :( help please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that you can use which I cobbled together. I highly recommend you familiarise your with Regular Expressions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

and here is a nice tester that I used: 
http://regexstorm.net/tester

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 string input = "for(i=0;i<10;i++)";
        string pattern = @"^(\w+)(\W)(\w)(\W).*$";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        string cycle = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
        string agrupation = matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
        string variable = matches[0].Groups[3].Value;
        string asignation = matches[0].Groups[4].Value;

        string test = string.Format("cycle: {0}, agrupation: {1}, variable={2}, asignation: {3}", cycle, agrupation, variable, asignation);

        Console.WriteLine(test);
```